# Insert unique item to NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I've implemented a simple code that used to insert unique items to NSArray object. Meaning that If the item already exists, it won't be added again to avoid duplications

```
BOOL identicalItemNotFound = 
    [self.tags indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:@"balboa"] == NSNotFound;

if (identicalItemNotFound) {
    self.tags = [self.tags arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:@[@"balboa"]];
}
```

I was wondering if there's already dedicated API for this ability ?

thanks

Comment: Why don't you use an `NSSet`?

Comment: Use `NSMutableOrderedSet`